# regex to check if a number exists in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list. I want to check if it contains a number

```
list1 = [u'Studied at ', u'South City College, Kolkata', u'Class of 2012',
u'Lives in   ', u'Calcutta, India', u'From ', u'Calcutta, India']
>>> if re.match(r'[\w-]+$', str(list1)):
    print "contains a number"
else:
    print "does not contain number"
```

It does not contain any number.
Need some help. I want the output to be "2012"

Comment: Where did you get that regex from? You're looking for a word character at the very end of the string, not specifically digits at all.

Comment: `[\w-]+$` matches a string that contains one or more alphanumeric characters or hyphens at the end of the string.

`re.match()` additionally anchors the search at the start of the string, so the overall operation will only return `True` if the entire string consists of alphanumerics (including `_`) and hyphens.

Answer (score 5):

How about `\d` regex?

```
>>> import re
>>> l = [u'Studied at ', u'South City College, Kolkata', u'Class of 2012', u'Lives in ', u'Calcutta, India', u'From ', u'Calcutta, India']
>>> digit_re = re.compile('\d')
>>> [item for item in l if digit_re.search(item)]
[u'Class of 2012']
```

Or, if you want to extract digits:

```
>>> for item in l:
...     match = digit_re.search(item)
...     if match:
...         print "%s: %s" % (item, match.group(1))
... 
Class of 2012: 2012
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do a `re.search` for the pattern `\d`. Don't `re.match`, that only matches from the start of the string.